# Helm - Remove double quotes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to remove double quotes from the below parameter in Kubernetes template file. Since the double quotes are there, the helm templating fails and not able to install Kubernetes template.

```yaml
      - ip: status.podIP
        hostnames: "
        - test.com
        - test2.com"
```

I have tried using Helm functions trimAll, toYaml but the quotes are not removed.

```yaml
      - ip: status.podIP
        hostnames: "
        - test.com
        - test2.com"
```

In the above YAML, I need to remove the double quotes, to make it as list.

Comment: Where do the double quotes come from?  If it's a file in your chart's `templates` directory, what stops you from just deleting them with a text editor?